Consistent "No route found" error with self hosted Lightning Node
I followed the Raspibolt guide on how to setup Lightning. Everything is up and running smoothly, except I consistently get issues with a route not being found for my payments... I've been running tests with small txs: sending some sats to myself, friends, and overall the experience seems unstable... Sometimes it works, other times I'm unable to find routes.
Right now, I only have 1 channel open. What do I need to do to have greater success, and an overall more stable experience when finding routes for my payments? Open more channels? Add more peers?
I tried opening a channel with Kraken, but quickly learned that some Lightning nodes set a minimum channel balance that... let's say is high for solo node runners like myself.
